# Is there a word to describe limbs or other body parts arranged in sets of 5?

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically, I was looking for a word to describe Lovecraft's Elder Things: "The top appendage was a head adorned with five eyes, five eating tubes... The bottom appendage was five-limbed... The beings also had five leathery, fan-like retractable wings and five sets of branching tentacles that sprouted from their torsos."

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 2):

[Pentadactyl:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pentadactyl)

> having five digits on each hand or foot

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use ***[pentapod](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pentapod)***.

*[Penta](https://www.lexico.com/definition/penta-)* is a Greek prefix which means *five* and *[-pod](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/-pod)* is also from Greek which means *foot/limb* etc.

> An organism or a machine with five legs. [[Wikitionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pentapod)

You might have heard *tripod stand* which is a three-legged stand in laboratories.

> Most of the dominant lifeforms on Pandora have six limbs, making them what's known as ***hexapoda*** (Greek for "six legs"). Some hexapods in the movie are a horse-like creature called the Direhorse, a panther-like creature called a Viperwolf, and a pterodactyl-like creature called a Mountain Banshee. All of them have six limbs.
>
> On Earth, most creatures are ***tetrapods***, meaning they have four limbs. That includes everything from dogs to horses to humans. The only creatures that have six limbs are insects.
>
>  [[The Geek Twins]](http://www.thegeektwins.com/2010/06/flawed-science-of-avatar-six-legs.html?m=1)